# How to layer a image underneath components in React NEXT.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I'm trying to make a website and using this Canadian politicians [site](https://www.pierre4pm.ca/) as a reference. I like how his navbar and join components layer on top of his picture, and how his picture is a fixed length and resizing the window resized the picture only a little bit based on the layered components but also keeps the aspect ratio correct and unstretched.

My first problem is I'm using NEXT.JS Image components and I can't figure out how to make it copy that behaviour of not stretching while maintaining a fixed size.

I'm a python boy I just got put on this project so my second problem is I made a nav bar component and am going to get around to the component in place of his join component, but I can't figure out how his website layers so nicely. In what direction should I look into. Thank You!

Comment: You need to look into CSS, specifically backgrounds and positioning. NextJS doesn't matter here much, this is basic layout stuff that applies to anything HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a css issue than a NEXT.JS issue.

The key is to use an image as a background of a `<div>` tag (or any tag), rather than an `<img>` tag. Use the following properties

```css
background-image: url('....');
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: This isn't the code I used to solve it but it helped me onto the right track so thank you!

Comment: Yup, that was just a general guideline, not a direct solution to your problem :)